# Getting error code 10474 is coming in paypal recurring payment in opencart

Tags: paypal, opencart

During Recurring payment in paypal, error code 10474(This transaction cannot be processed. The shipping country is not allowed by the buyer's country of residence) is coming,how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can only resolve this by switching payment gateways, or adding another payment gateway to run alongside PayPal. The problem isn't with your OpenCart, it's because Paypal does not allow certain countries to use their service.

Comment: if we edit paypal account details can we resolve this problem?

Comment: No. The problem is that PayPal restricts certain countries from using their services and if the buyer is in one of these countries, they will not be allowed to purchase anything through Paypal.

Comment: So if buyer country changes(like USA),it will be ok?

Comment: You mean like getting the customer to go through a proxy server?

Comment: No.Opencart customer's country.

Comment: As long as your buyers are in a country not restricted by Paypal, there will be no problem. Alternatively, you can also uncheck the countries restricted from your GEO locations, thus not selling in those countries.